# React JS — How to access a variable from a onScroll function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, scope

I need help on how to access a variable that is set inside a function. The function `onScroll` reads a the offsetY of a scrolling component. The variable value receives a constant changing integer based on the offsetY divided by the item height. This creates a range of 0 to 12 that I intend to use in another component. The issue is that I cannot access this ever-changing variable outside this function. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

**Pseudo-code**

- onScroll() capture the offsetY of the ScrollComponent
- access the offsetY from info.point.y
- divide it by the itemHeight, round it and make it positive
- set the current integer in value
- pass value into a PageComponent
- change page based on the offsetY

...

```
const itemHeight = 56
const numItem = data.length
const listHeight = numItem * 56

let value // To be accessed by a component

function onScroll(info) {
    value = Math.abs(Math.round(info.point.y / itemHeight))
    console.log(value)
    return value // I cannot find a way to access this value
}
```

...

```
    <Page
        currentPage={value}
    >
        {data.map((value, i) => {
            return (
                <Frame
                    width={"100%"}
                    style={page}
                    key={i}
                >
                    {value.firstName} {value.lastName}
                </Frame>
            )
        })}
    </Page>
```

Comment: Why don't you make `value` a state of the component?

Comment: Hi Zain, I actually did try that. For some strange reason, the value becomes 0 when I use hooks inside that function. ` const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0) `

Comment: Can you please share the code what you did for state?

Comment: Thanks Zain. After I looked into the code, your suggestion worked.